# Async task for my login android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

After i implement my login codes into the async task doInBackground method, my application crashes. I needed this help because if i dont implement async task for login, my application in the real device will crash due to policy issue. Can i konw where my errors is?

Below is my doInBackground task:

```
// Checking login in background
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Store user details in SQLite Database
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    // Clear all previous data in database
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                    // Launch HomePage Screen
                    Intent homepage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomepageActivity.class);

                    // Close all views before launching HomePage
                    homepage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(homepage);

                    // Close Login Screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And here is my logcat:

```
08-18 22:34:59.088: E/JSON(382): {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"502cfeb2e60004.54904838","user":{"name":"user1","email":"user1@gmail.com","created_at":"2012-08-16 22:07:46","updated_at":null}}
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5139)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5364)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2688)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:119)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.LoginActivity$Login.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-18 22:34:59.137: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  ... 4 more
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382): Activity com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f0a510 that was originally added here
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44f0a510 that was originally added here
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.LoginActivity$Login.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:106)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:60)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4121)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4431)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:318)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-18 22:35:01.867: E/WindowManager(382):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the view in the doInBackground function which happens in the background thread. View should always be updated in the UI thread. To solve this, you can return the JSONObject from the doInBackground function and do the processing in the onPostExecute method.

Move the try block after `userFunction.loginUser(email, password);` to onPostExecute.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

    return json;
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    // check for login response
    try {
        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
            loginErrorMsg.setText("");
            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                // user successfully logged in
                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                // Clear all previous data in database
                userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                // Launch HomePage Screen
                Intent homepage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomepageActivity.class);

                // Close all views before launching HomePage
                homepage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(homepage);

                // Close Login Screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // Error in login
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont mind show me some example? cause im totally new to android

Comment: Ok! i try moving that and see

Comment: Okok. i solve my code by adding in the runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {

Answer (score 1):

You can only update Views from UI thread. So, move code which updates Views to `onPostExecute`.

Also, consider reading stack trace. Your error is self explanatory.

Comment: what do you mean by views? the 'startActivity(homepage)' in my code?

Comment: In your case, TextView. This line:  loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");

Comment: Okok. i solve my code by adding in the runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

Comment: @JonesCh that's a odd approach, onPostExecute is designed for that purpoises.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `View`'s properties inside `doInBackground()` method, that means you can't call `setText` method to update a `TextView`.

You can resolve your issue by move your code to the `onPostExecute` method or by doing something like to each one of your `Views` inside the `doInBackground()` method:

```
loginErrorMsg.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            loginErrorMsg.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Let me know if it works to you.

Comment: Okok. i solve my code by adding in the runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {